# Rendering border-radius in Safari for Mac

Tags: safari, border, css

I have a problem with rendering of corners of elements, which have border-radius.

I use the following code and it works in all major browsers on Windows, including Safari.

```
border: 1px solid #555;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Now my client has a Mac and a Safari browser and the following are screen shots of the ugly borders rendering, which is the problem.
[image: Corners in Mac Safari]

Does anyone know what is the reason of such rendering ? ([The original page](http://imd-engineering.com))

Comment: maybe the webkit on his mac osx version is glitchy, it may take some unexpected decisions, try -webkit-appearance: none; to see if it solves the border-radius issue

Answer (score -1):

You should try for Mac Safari

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```